# Array exceed allowed size in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, array

I have a function that accepts as parameter an array like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(some_data custom_datum[]) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
        create table foo_table as (

           select
           coalesce(foo_ind, bar_ind, ter_ind) as foobarter,
           import_date,

           -- do some stuff here

           from unnest (some_data) as T
           group by grouping sets ((foo_ind, import_date), (bar_ind, import_date), (ter_ind, import_date))
        );
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The input array is generated by another function `foo`. So I call everything in this way:

```
select my_func(array(select foo()));
```

where the function `foo` is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS SETOF custom_datum
```

The problem is that for a big amount of data `array(select foo())` returns:

> ERROR:  array size exceeds the maximum allowed (1073741823)

What I am trying to workaround is the lack of possibility to pass different functions, as at the moment, the input array gets generated by different functions:

```
select my_func(array(select foo()));
select my_func(array(select bar()));
select my_func(array(select ter()));
.... etc
```

How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: Passing in an array like that is usually a horrible idea, paste the definition of `my_func`

Comment: the definition of `my_func` is there

Comment: @Randomize I see the signature only.

Comment: I put the function. Yes actually I create and unnest an array which is quite useless but the problem is, how can I pass a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your `my_func` is essentially doing is creating a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) -- a materialized view is a cached copy of a result set stored as a table. Drop the function and use the normal `MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

Skip generating an array -- waste of a time and space and may even be serializing the result set to disk twice. And, instead, just use something like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW foo_view
AS
  SELECT whatever
  FROM wherever
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (foo_ind, import_date),
    (bar_ind, import_date),
    (ter_ind, import_date)
  );
```

Now you can "refresh" this by doing `REFRESH foo_view;`

Comment: The problem is that I am workaround different kind of inputs. Please read my updated question.

Comment: @Randomize how did your function `my_func` return the table name of the table it generated?

Comment: it is not doing it at the moment

Comment: So what good is it?. You have a function that generates a table if it doesn't exist and the rest of your code base assumes that it all went as planned and queries it based on the hard-coded table name?

Comment: Yes, what I need right now is just being able to reuse code passing a specific type of data independently from the source. All the checks will come after.

Comment: So if you insist, just pass the query as text to generate the materialized view in the sql function... Or just remove that silly wrapper and changer your work flow a little bit to be more sql-esque.

Comment: Just FYI @Randomize, A SQL array is a container type. It's not meant to hold a result set. And doing that is going to sting no way around it -- it's going to be worse in every way (slower, memory intensive, less terse, etc)

Comment: btw what do you mean for making it more sql-esh? What I am trying to do it is making more reusable the code. SQL (for my limited knowledge of it) is usually less flexible than general purpose languages so I end up to look for workaround like that.

Comment: SQL is a declarative language that has a declarative method that takes a query and generates an on disk cache of that query. You don't need to write a function that accepts an array, or accepts a text query, you just need `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` that's sql-esque. That's the SQL way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly limit the output of `foo()`:

```
SELECT foo() LIMIT 10000;
```

Or, most probably better, avoid using arrays altogether (pass the set, not an array made of it).  For this, you will, of course, have to rewrite `my_func()`.  Thinking about it, I can imagine that this will be beneficial from a performance point of view, too.